# Efficient way to transfer data from one django application to another

Tags: django, performance, client-server, xml-rpc

Currently, I'm working on a project where I have a server - client relationship between two django applications running on separate hosts.

The server has to store and provide a large amount of relational data, eg: Suppliers, Companys, Products, etc etc..

The client downloads data on request from the server and adds it to their database. clients can also upload from their station to the database to expand it.

The previous person that developed this used XMLRPC to transfer the vast (13MB typical) XML file from server to client. now really all we're sending are database agnostic objects to be stored in a database so i wondered if there was a more efficient way of doing it?

Please ask for more details if you need them, I wasn't really sure what you'd need to know

EDIT: Efficient in terms of Networking, and Server Side Processing. Clients can do the heavy lifting.

Comment: efficient in terms of network bandwidth? in terms of processing needed  to transform the raw data into database ready format?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A shared database design seems more suitable. But of course there may be security, political or organisational reasons ruling that out. Plus there would be significant re-design required.

To reduce network bandwidth first check that HTTP gzip compression is enabled.

If it's just a dumb data transfer JSON would generally be a lot more compact than XMLRPC. Does the data look amenable to a straight translation to JSON? This would still require some server-side processing.

For minimal server-side processing (if the database tables are relatively similar) it may be very efficient to just send the client a dump of the relevant db query. Of course unless the tables have the same schema you would have to do some client-side processing of raw SQL, which is not ideal.

Comment: Client and server are other sides of the internet, and the client can't be trusted with access directly, how do i enable gzip on python xmlrpc?, Json would probably be better as it is a data transfer that is generated on the fly, and the tables are almost exactly the same both sides.

Comment: you can check if gzip is enabled on the server by looking at the response headers in firbug or equivelant. As for enabling it - choose your layer - it can be done in your web server (check its docs), in Django middleware -  https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/middleware/#module-django.middleware.gzip - or per view - https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/decorators/#gzip-compression

Comment: ok, so how would i go about encoding my objects (querysets) to json?

Comment: so what i'd do is take your code that generates XMLRCP and see if you can rewrite it to use `django.utils.simplejson` - I'd recommend a couple of hours playing with dummy data in an interactive shell. `simplejson` is well documented and the JSON format is very easy to work with.

Comment: simplejson doesn't like django's querysets ( was already playing :P ) but I'm now trying to see if I can get django's built-in serialiser to work